# If something name is one of file name

Tags: java, list, file, bukkit

im creating minecraft sectors system..

I want to get worldguard region what player is actually.

All regions are saved into files like (Regions/region1.yml, region2.yml)

Now my question is:

How can i list all files in folder regions to String list?

i need it to do something like this

if(e.getregion.getiid.contains(list1) {

//do something
}

Answer (score 2):

you can use list function of File class [http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#list()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#list%28%29)

```
File regionFolder = new File("path/to/Regions/folder");
String[] regionFile = regionFolder.list();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to leverage the capabilities of ArrayList to check if a String is in the list, you can do this:

```
File regionFolder = new File("/path/to/files");

FileFilter filter = new FileFilter() {
     @Override
     public boolean accept(File pathname) {
         return pathname.getPath().endsWith(".yml");
     }
};

ArrayList<String> myYmlFiles = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(regionFolder.list(filter)));
```

You can then use .contains on the myYmlFiles object, and it will only contain your .yml files.

```
if ( myYmlFiles.contains(e.getRegion().getId()) ) {
    // do something
}
```